# Google Marker Position Option: retrieving Latitude and Longitude from Google Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables

I have a column called 'xy' in Google Fusion Table.  Values are exactly in this format in each cell:
30.319067,-97.739454

I have created an array of these values, var locationList = [].
Trying to use this array and retrieve the lat, long data to put in for the position option, but it's not recognizing it.  I have an alert function below, to see what's being passed, and it alerts (NaN, NaN).

```
for (var i = 0; i < locationList.length ; i++){
    if (obj.id == i){
        alert(locationList[0]);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:Map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationList[i]),
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            zoom: 0});

        break;}


}
```

Can anybody tell me what's going on with these values being passed? Is it the format problem...? Data type problem?

I also have the 'Geometry' column in my Fusion Table in this format:

```
<Point><coordinates>-97.739454,30.319067,0.0</coordinates></Point>
```

Not sure which column suits the best for the Marker position.  Whichever the column, I just want to see that marker bouncing!

Thanks for your help!

---

I have created two different columns for latitude and longitude and they are in the number data type in my Fusion Table. The data are in arrays var latitudeList = []; and var longitudeList = [];.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numRow ; i++){
    if (obj.id == i){
        alert(latitudeList[3]);
        alert(nameList[i]);

        var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitudeList[i]),parseFloat(longitudeList[i]));

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map:PuppyMap,
            position: LatLng,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            zoom: 0});

        alert([i]); break;}
};
```

Now I'm again using the alert to see what's going on, and             alert(latitudeList[0]); 
alerts (30.23423, NaN), with parenthesis, I don't understand. Each cell contains the latitude values as 30.xxxxx as numbers, and they should be in the array that way.
And alert(parseFloat(latitudeList[0]),parseFloat(longitudeList[0]));
alerts NaN.

I guess I'm not sure what NaN is,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two numbers as its arguments, not a string containing two numbers separated by a comma.  This is not correct:

```
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:Map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locationList[i]),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        zoom: 0});
```

should be

```
    var coords = locationList[i].split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:Map,
        position: latlng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        zoom: 0});
```

and safer to be:

```
    var coords = locationList[i].split(',');
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:Map,
        position: latlng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        zoom: 0});;
```

as coming from the FusionTable it is a string.  You could even verify they are valid numbers, by testing "isNaN" before using them to construct the google.maps.LatLng.

Comment: Two arguments! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hi again, I created two separate columns for latitude and longitude for two arguments to no avail. I have added my question to my original post... I really appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you querying the FusionTable?  Where do latitudeList and longitudeList come from?

Comment: I'm using Google Visualization on Google Fusion Table.

Comment: I was looking for the code that does that.  Please add it to your question (or create a new question that includes it for this new problem).

Comment: Please read the codes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170965/fusion-table-query-via-google-visualization