# Fusion Table Query via Google Visualization

Tags: google-visualization, google-fusion-tables

```
function createBoundingBox() {
outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
var queryList = [];
queryList.push("SELECT 'WEB', 'NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'Lat', 'Lng', 'WEB1' FROM ");
queryList.push(Table);
queryList.push(" WHERE " + where + " AND ");
queryList.push("ST_INTERSECTS('GEOMETRY', ");
queryList.push("RECTANGLE(LATLNG");
queryList.push(sw);
queryList.push(", LATLNG");
queryList.push(ne);
queryList.push("))");
var query = encodeURIComponent(queryList.join(''));
var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
    'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + query);

gvizQuery.send(function(response) {

    numRow = response.getDataTable().getNumberOfRows();
    var datatable = response.getDataTable();


    if (datatable && datatable.getNumberOfRows()) {
     //   var linkList = [];

        var newLinkList = [];




        for (var i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
            var name = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 1);
            nameList.push(name);
            var address = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 2);
            addressList.push(address);
            var latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3));   alert(latitude)
            latitudeList.push(latitude);
            var longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4));
            longitudeList.push(longitude);
            var newLink = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 5);
            newLinkList.push("<a name = 'link' id="+"'" + i + "'" + "onmouseover='getId(this)' href=" + newLink + " target='_blank'>" + name + "</a>");



            infoContent.push("name" + name + "<br>address: "+address);

            //       var link = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 0);
   //         linkList.push(link);


        }

        names = newLinkList.join("<br>") ;
        outputDiv.innerHTML = numRow+ " results nearby " + sAddress + "<br><br>";
        outputDiv.innerHTML += names;


    }



});

}
```

This is the code that is querying the data from the Fusion Table.  I'm wondering why the Latitude and Longitude are showing up as (30.xxx, NaN) and (-97.xxx, NaN) when it should be just 30.xxx and -97.xxx.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is the code that is outputing the (30.xxx,Nan) and (-97.xxx,NaN)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, column 3 in your data is latitude and column 4 is longitude, correct?  If so, then your problem is that you are using `google.maps.LatLng` incorrectly.  The `LatLng` constructor expects a (lat, long) pair as the arguments, ie:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

and it returns a LatLng object.  So, when you call it like this:

```
var latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3));
var longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4));
```

the constructor thinks you are giving it a latitude with no longitude each time.  What you want to do is this:

```
var inputLatitude = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3);
var inputLongitude = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3);
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(inputLatitude, inputLongitude);
latitudeList.push(latLng.lat());
longitudeList.push(latLng.lng());
```

Comment: Oh my god, I think you're right, I don't know when I did that - changed it to google.maps.LatLng. Thank you, I'm going to change it and see what happens.

Comment: Lord, that was it. Thank you so much. And Thank you 'geocodezip' as well for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 var latitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(1, 3));   
 latitudeList.push(latitude);
 var longitude = new google.maps.LatLng(response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4));
 longitudeList.push(longitude);
```

Probably should be:

```
 var latitude =response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3);
 latitudeList.push(latitude);
 var longitude = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4);
 longitudeList.push(longitude);
```

Or put the combined google.maps.LatLng onto a single array

```
 var latitude =response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 3);
 var longitude = response.getDataTable().getValue(i, 4);
 latlngList.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));
```

Comment: Oh  I actually just changed it to '1' 30 minutes ago to feed it in to the alert function to, again, see what's being fed... It didn't work with 'i'